# selenium click doesn't work alternative to java script executor click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have selenium click functions implemented by `.click()` which includes `webdriver wait`, `sleep` methods and also used by Actions. None of them works stable, in other words, they work sometimes. I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar

I got a work around using `Javascript executor` as below which works most of the time.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Can any one suggest a better way for this or an alternative to java script as i read many website that java script executor is not recommended.

If not any better explanation why should we go to java script executor rather normal click().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown when it doesn't work?

Comment: @Sai no exceptions are throws, it just do click operation and move to next step but in actual it doesnt click on the button.

Comment: What type of synchronization do you use and what is the max wait time?

Comment: using Conditional Synchronization 'webdriver wait' with wait until element is clickable. Max wait time is 60 sec. But not working

Answer (score 0):

```
//where driver is an instance of WebDriver that you have initialized and now displays the web page of interest
//and where elementToBeClicked is an instance of class By, e.g. By elementToBeClicked = By.id("myButton");
Wait<WebDriver> wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
WebElement aLinkOrButton = wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToBeClicked));
aLinkOrButton.click();
```

Comment: using below code also doesnt work.                              'Wait<WebDriver> wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
WebElement aLinkOrButton = wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToBeClicked));
aLinkOrButton.click();' is there any alternative for this other than JavaScriptExecutor

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if it doesn't work.. :)

Try using "visibilityOfElementLocated".

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
WebElement aLinkOrButton =     wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(elementToBeClicked));
aLinkOrButton.click();
```